# Can I assign Vue.js data property to a local variable along with it's setter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Please see this minimum example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ count }}
    <button @click="click">Click</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    click() {
      this.count++
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I have a count data property and a button that will increase the count.

Now, I want to do this a little differently like this(for some reason)

```js
click() {
  let count = this.count
  count += 1
}
```

I want to assign my data property to my local variable first, and then increase the local variable count, and hopefully, triggers Vue's reactivity.

I know Vue use `Object.defineProperty`'s setter to data property, how can I clone those setters?

Is it possible to do this?

#### Update

What I want to do is trying to simplify below code

```
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isALoading: false,
      isBLoading: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    hitAPI(type: "A" | "B") {
      if (type === "A") {
        this.isALoading = true;
        fetch(someAPI)
          .then(() => {
            this.isALoading = false;
          })
          .catch(() => {
            this.isALoading = false;
          });
      } else {
        this.isBLoading = true;
        fetch(someAPI)
          .then(() => {
            this.isBLoading = false;
          })
          .catch(() => {
            this.isBLoading = false;
          });
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to "copy" a setter like that into a local variable.

You can abstract the property behind a method or another object with its own setter:

```es6
click() {
  const self = this
  const wrapper = {
    get count() { return self.count },
    set count(x) { self.count = x }
  }

  wrapper.count++
}
```

I sense this is an XY problem; why do you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve?

You are best to just reassign back the local variable to the data property to trigger the update:

```es6
click() {
  let count = this.count

  // Modify local var
  count++

  // Assign back to trigger the update
  this.count = count
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can dynamically access the property by its string name:

```es6
hitAPI(type: "A" | "B") {
  const prop = type === "A" ? "isALoading" : "isBLoading"
  this[prop] = true

  fetch(someAPI).finally(() => {
    this[prop] = false
  })
}
```

Alternatively with `async`/`await`:

```es6
async hitAPI(type: "A" | "B") {
  const prop = type === "A" ? "isALoading" : "isBLoading"
  this[prop] = true

  try {
    await fetch(someAPI)
  } finally {
    this[prop] = false
  }
}
```